# C#.NET : Add Scrollbar to Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I need to add a scrollbar to worksheet and link cell to it using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library and C#.NET.

The correspoding VBA code is like this:

```
    ActiveSheet.ScrollBars.Add(545.25, 172.5, 398.25, 24.75).Select
With Selection
    .Value = 0
    .Min = 0
    .Max = 100
    .SmallChange = 1
    .LargeChange = 10
    .LinkedCell = "$A$1"
    .Display3DShading = True
End With
```

I tried the below code, it added Scrollbar but not working as expected and also unable to link cell to it.

```
oSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.ScrollBar.1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 545.25, 172.5, 398.25, 24.75);
```

My C#.NET Code adds scrollbar as an object to Excel, where as i need it as a control. It seems there is a difference in it.

Actual Result using my C#.NET code is attached as image below

[image: Actual Result using my C# code]

But the Expected result is attached as image below:

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838642.aspx).
Yes earlier I was adding ActiveX Object in place of Control. The below code works fine.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

                   :
                   :

Excel.ControlFormat Scrollbar  = oSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(Excel.XlFormControl.xlScrollBar, 545, 172, 398, 24).ControlFormat;

Scrollbar.Value = 0;
Scrollbar.Min = 0;
Scrollbar.Max=100;
Scrollbar.SmallChange = 1;
Scrollbar.LargeChange = 10;
Scrollbar.LinkedCell = "$A$1";
```